# Is there a way to dynamically import Python objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a command handler, here's some code:

```
from importlib import import_module
from os import path, listdir

client.commands = [] # where the commands are stored
directory = '.\\src\\exec\\files'
for command in listdir(directory):
    filepath = path.join(directory, filename)
    if path.isdir(filepath) and 'lib' not in filepath: # check if file is a directory
        log_commands(directory=filepath) # make recursive logging

    elif filename.endswith('.py'):
        command_name = filename.split('\\')[-1]
        module_name = devutils.filepath2module(filepath, True, True) # convert file path to module path
        client_utils.commands[command_name] = import_module(module_name) # puts module in a new item
```

The code works fine, but the *import_module* function imports only the entire function. I was wondering if there's some library that imports specific objects from the module, like:

```
from module import object
```

But in a dynamic way, I searched a little bit and couldn't find anything. (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: You *always* import the entire module. You can *choose* to only extract a name from the global namespace, they *type* of the object is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from module import foo` is equivalent to `foo = __import__('module').foo`. It does have to run the whole file to create the module object.

But `importlib.import_module` is a bit easier to use (especially for submodules) so that would be

```
foo = import_module('module').foo
```

If the attribute access also needs to be dynamic, you can use `getattr`, so

```
def from_module_get(module_name, attr):
    return getattr(import_module(module_name), attr)
```

```
>>> from_module_get('math', 'tau')
6.283185307179586
```